# Проблемы с сортировкой матрицы

Tags: c

Пытаюсь отсортировать матрицу по возрастанию строчечных элементов методом выбора, но по факту сортируется только 1 строка (и почему-то 0 не поддается сортировке), а все остальные остаются как прежне. Прилагаю ниже сам код (хотя и кодом его назвать сложно, уж извините)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 5
void swap(int *xp, int *yp) {
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;

}
void selectionSort(int arr[]) {

    int i, j, min_idx;

    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
                min_idx = j;

            // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
            if (min_idx != i)
                swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
/* Function to print an array */
int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    static int arr[n][n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("arr[%d][%d] = ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf_s("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("old array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf ("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    selectionSort ((int *) arr);
    printf("\nnew array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf ("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Результат компиляции]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смена значений найденного минимального значения у вас должна быть после поиска. А вы сделали внутри цикла поиска минимального значения.

```
for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
        min_idx = j; } // здесь должен быть конец цикла

            // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
if (min_idx != i) // после цикла должно быть
    swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
        //}
```

То, что сортируется только одна строка, так вы запустили только один раз с адресом первой строки. Вызывайте для каждой строки.

```
for(int i=n;i;){
  --i;
  selectionSort (arr[i]);}
```